# ASP Web API Controller with Entity Framework very slow and strange results

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have 3 tables `OPERATORS` (20 records), `SALES` (7000 records), `SALES_DETAIL` (36000 records).

Using Entity Framework with a database-first approach in Visual Studio 2015 I want to create a Web Api controller that returns only operators for current opened sales (`CLOSE_DATA==null`):

```
public  IQueryable <OPERATORS> GetOPERATORS()
{
    IQueryable<OPERATORS> c = from co in db.SALES
                              join op in db.OPERATORS on co.ID_OP equals op.ID
                              where co.CLOSE_DATA == null
                              select op;
    return c;
}
```

Equivalent SQL run in SQL Server Management Studio returns the correct result, 3 records in 0.00 ms.

```
select o.* 
from OPERATORS o 
inner join SALES c on c.ID_OP = o.id 
where c.CLOSE_DATA is null
```

In browser api controller returns large amount of data and browser almost is freezing, in fiddler answer is got very slow and I can see data from `SALES_DETAIL` that I didn't include in my query?

If I change the action in controller to return a `Long` and return `c.Count()`, the result is correct : 3.

Why is `SALES_DETAIL` included and why is the query so very slow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try 2 options here.

**Option 1 :** You can **disable** the `lazy loading` for `whole project` as shown below.

```
public YourContext()
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

**Option 2 :** **Turning off** `lazy loading` for specific navigation properties as shown below.i.e. turned off by making the `SaleDetails` property `non-virtual`

```
public class YourModel 
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public ICollection<SaleDetail> SaleDetails { get; set; }  
}
```

Here is an useful link for you : [**Lazy Loading**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy)

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize/improve your query by adding AsNoTracking:

**Entity Framework exposes a number of performance tuning options to help you optimise the performance of your applications. One of these tuning options is .AsNoTracking()**

So your query will look like this:

```
var query = from co in db.SALES.AsNoTracking()
               join op in db.OPERATORS.AsNoTracking()
               on co.ID_OP equals op.ID
               where co.CLOSE_DATA == null
               select op;
   return query.ToList();
```

To make that call non-blocking, you can take advantage of async calls in EF:

```
public async Task<IList<OPERATORS>> GetOPERATORS()
{
    var query = from co in db.SALES.AsNoTracking()
                   join op in db.OPERATORS.AsNoTracking()
                   on co.ID_OP equals op.ID
                   where co.CLOSE_DATA == null
                   select op;
       return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```